# Rails ordering of collections by proc

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to sort a collection using a custom proc. I know Rails has the order method, but I don't believe this works with procs, so I'm just using sort_by instead. Can someone go into detail about the speed I'm sacrificing, or suggest alternatives? My understanding is that the exact implementation of order will depend on the adapter (which, in my case, is mysql), but I'm wondering if there are ways to take advantage of this to speed the sort up.

As an example, I want to do this:

```
Model.order(|m| m.get_priority )
```

but am forced to do this

```
Model.all.sort_by{|m| m.get_priority}
```

Comment: What is the definition for `get_priority`?

Comment: Say that model "n" belongs_to model "m" and "m" has_many "n."

Then, get_priority is the number of n that belong to an instance of m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort_by` is implemented at Ruby level and it's part of Ruby, not ActiveRecord. Therefore, the sorting will not be executed by the database, rather by the Ruby interpreter.

This is not an optimal solution as DBMS are generally more efficient at sorting data as they may use existing indexes.

If `get_priority` performs some sort of computation outside the database, then you don't have a lot of alternatives to the code you posted here unless you want to cache the result of the `get_priority` as a column in the `Model` table and sort against it using the ActiveRecord `order` statement that will result in an `ORDER BY` SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks Simone. What you stated was pretty much what I suspected, but I wanted someone who knew more to confirm it. Now I basically have to decide if I want speed, or to add code to measure this priority state (as you guessed, it involves calculations with other entities in the database).